# How to solve a polynomial equation for one unknown in python?

Tags: python, scipy, equation, solver, root-finding

I have been trying to solve the following equation for R1 in python using scipy, but I get the error:

```
result = root_scalar(equation, bracket=[0, 8])
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[1638], line 1
    result = root_scalar(equation, bracket=[0, 8])

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_root_scalar.py:275 in root_scalar
    r, sol = methodc(f, a, b, args=args, **kwargs)

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_zeros_py.py:784 in brentq
    r = _zeros._brentq(f, a, b, xtol, rtol, maxiter, args, full_output, disp)

ValueError: f(a) and f(b) must have different signs
```

The equation is:

```
K= 10**(a0 + (a1 * np.log10(R1/R2)) + (a2 * (np.log10(R1/R2))**2) + (a3 * (np.log10(R1/R2))**3) + (a4 * (np.log10(R1/R2))**4)) + 0.0166
```

The code that I have been using is the following:

```
R2 = 0.002294000005349517
K = 0.09539999812841415

a0 = -1.1358
a1 = -2.1146
a2 = 1.6474
a3 = -1.1428
a4 = -0.6190

def equation(log_R1_R2):
    x = log_R1_R2
    return 10**(a0 + a1*x + a2*x**2 + a3*x**3 + a4*x**4) - (K - 0.0166)

result = root_scalar(equation, bracket=[0, 8])
log_R1_R2 = result.root
R1 = R2 * 10**log_R1_R2
```

Comment: Please post the full error stack trace (which will include what this error is referring to).

Comment: Please provide enough information for someone to recreate the problem (i.e. the "known values").

Comment: What have you done to try and solve this problem?

Comment: I have tried to change the bracket=[-1, 8] to various combinations. Also, if I thy this equation for single R2 and K numbers it works, but when I use it for the whole dataset the problem arises. Maybe there are issues with some values from my dataset? a values are constants.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [ask] and write a [mcve].

Comment: The error message and the [documentation of `root_scalar`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root_scalar.html) is pretty clear. The `bracket` parameter you are providing needs to have different signs when calling the function with those values.

Comment: Do yourself a favor: plot that function before you choose your bracket values.  The plot will show you where the zeros are if they exist.

Comment: I have updated the code for a single example, in order for everyone to be able to reproduce the code. Thank you!

Comment: When I adjust the brackets, the code works for these R2 and K values, but the same error arises for other values of R2 and K.

Comment: This is a 4th order polynomial.  It may have up to four roots.  A plot will show you where they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem seems better suited for a polynomial root solver. Using the [`numpy.polynomial.Polynomial`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.html#numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial) class, we can create the polynomial in question, get the roots, and find `R1` using those roots. As for which roots you want to use, that's for you to decide since I don't know the application.

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial

R2 = 0.002294000005349517
K = 0.09539999812841415

a0 = -1.1358
a1 = -2.1146
a2 = 1.6474
a3 = -1.1428
a4 = -0.6190

p = Polynomial([-np.log10(K - 1/60) + a0, a1, a2, a3, a4])
roots = p.roots()
print(roots)
R1 = R2*10**roots
```

Output (i.e. the roots):

```py
[-3.07249423+0.j, -0.0149377 +0.j, 0.62061419-0.86009349j, 0.62061419+0.86009349j]
```